# 日本語に違和感のある箇所をおしえてください

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, 日本語, プライベートベータ

私の母国語が日本語ではないため、翻訳をしっかりとチェックしても、日本語の自然さを判断できない箇所が多いです。ですので、変な日本語を見つけたら、スタック・オーバーフローMetaにて[質問を投稿してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)。

例：

1. 上記の「件の質問」は英語では「Questions」になっており、日本語では「質問」になるべき
2. 下記の「ここで機能する」は英語では「Work Here」になっており、日本語では「ここで働く」になるべき

数多くあるため、当サイトを使いながら、変な箇所を見つけたら、[Metaに](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F:%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3+%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)投稿してください。

**下記のタグを適用してください：**

[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)[日本語](/questions/tagged/%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)

スクリーンショットもあると助かります。正しい日本語も添えていただけると最高です。

ご協力よろしくお願い致します！

Comment: > ここで登録してください
質問として投稿すればいいのですよね? この質問への回答ではなく。

Comment: @ento 編集しました。「ここ」＝「Meta」（日本語が分かりやすくなくて、申し訳ありません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうかなと思いましたが、念のため =)