# 日本語に違和感: サイドバーの「リンク先」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

サイト内の場所: 質問のサイドバー

例えば、以下の2つの質問は

(リンク元) [スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%B8%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D)  
(リンク先) [日本語に違和感のある箇所をおしえてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E7%AE%87%E6%89%80)

という関係ですが、「日本語に違和感のある箇所」質問を見ると、「リンク元」の「スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ」が「リンク先」欄に表示されます。

[image: リンク先]

これは仕様上、リンク先もリンク元も同じサイドバーに表示されるからですが、訳語としては間違っていることになります。

今のところ適切な訳語が思いつかないのですが、何がいいでしょうか。

- リンクされている質問: ちょっと長い・ちょっと不自然
- リンクされた質問: ちょっと不自然?
- リンク集: 質問以外も含まれそう
- リンク先・リンク元： 無粋だが無難
- リンク: 短すぎてわかりにくい?
- トラックバック: 古い? それに全く違うコンセプトを導入しないほうがいいように思う

Comment: これを実行しますが、どっちの言葉を使うかが悩み中です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

トラックバックでもないですね。ポスト中（質問・回答・コメントも含む）にリンクがあれば、自動的にここをまとめるらしいです。質問意外は含めるかどうか知りませんが、別の「Linked Questions」の項目があるため、「リンク集」がベストと思っています。

> リンク集

に適用済です。